# Are loops executed in sequence or in parallel on the gpu?

Tags: opengl, glsl, gpu

My question is about GLSL language. When I run a for loop in a vertex shader, is the loop executed sequentially or in parallel on the GPU?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No single invocation of a shader is executed "in parallel". Different invocations of the same shader (for example, the same vertex shader but given two different input values from two different vertices) are executed in parallel, but every shader acts sequentially (or if it doesn't, it must behave *as if* it acts sequentially, which is the same thing).

Answer (score 1):

It's executed sequentially. Different instances of a Vertex shader program are executed in parallel among all the processed triangles.